# How can I add ActiveRecord attribute helper methods to virtual attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

ActiveRecord offers attribute helper methods such as `_?` and the "dirty" methods (`_changed?` etc.)

Is there a Rails way to define these same methods on non-persisted or "virtual" attributes?

I'm hoping for something like:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  some_macro :my_attribute

end


$ @my_class = MyClass.new
$ @my_class.my_attribute? # => false
$ @my_class.my_attribute_changed? # => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this was certainly something interesting to investigate. Apparently there is not a straight forward way to do this... here are two things I found

[From 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563118/activerecord-virtual-attributes-treaded-as-a-record-attributes)

[From 2011 - reinforces the 2009 post](http://anti-pattern.com/2011/3/22/dirty-associations-with-activerecord) but makes it a bit cleaner. You create a module that updates the attribute hash. From the Brandon Weiss post:

```
# app/models/dirty_associations.rb
module DirtyAssociations
  attr_accessor :dirty

  def make_dirty(record)
    self.dirty = true
  end

  def changed?
    dirty || super
  end
end

# app/models/lolrus.rb
class Lolrus
  include DirtyAssociations

  has_and_belongs_to_many :buckets,
                          :after_add    => :make_dirty,
                          :after_remove => :make_dirty
end
```

There is also this plugin [mentioned here](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/48-episode-46-january-29-2010/stories/374-dirty-associations) but I am not sure how useful it is for you.

Comment: Thanks @ScottJShea - sad to see that there's no native support for this though... :(